# moment#diff broken in IE8 for version 2.2.1

Tags: internet-explorer-8, momentjs

More generally, is v2.2.1 supported in IE8?

I had an app that was going into an infinite loop in IE8 and think I've tracked it down to a bad return value from `moment().diff()`. Using the Developer Tools window, I tried the following and this is what I get:

```
>>var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b) 
-1.#IND
```

I get that `-1.#IND` result any time I try to do a `diff` in the developer window, at least.

Is this a known issue? Is IE8 still supported? I'm wondering if it's not, because I went to the tests page and it failed about half of them...or could something else be wrong with my browser or setup that would cause these results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 is still supported, but it appears there were several items that fail unit test on IE with the 2.2.1 release.  These have been addressed for the next version.  If you need it immediately, try the latest develop version from the Github sources.

See:

- https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1127
- https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1114

Comment: Ah, I scanned open issues but didn't look at closed ones. Dead on! The moment.js from github (e544ea8667) fixed the issues I was seeing. Thanks!